# Problems with printf and ambiguous type variables

Tags: haskell, ambiguous, type-variables

I have a little ambiguous type variable problem. I love haskell but this is really what I still fail to handle.
The problem is very easy and involves printf from Text.Printf. Since the problem is very general I'll just but in some sample code:

```
program = do
    d <- addd 4 8
    printf "%d" d

addd x y = return (x+y)
```

Of course printf is imported. The compiler then gives me an, obvious, ambiguous type variable error between Num and PrintfArg. I just don't know where to fit in the right type signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few places you could put a type signature. Firstly, addd has most general type of (and the most general type is (almost always) what GHC infers when you leave off the signature):

```
addd :: (Monad m, Num a) => a -> a -> m a
```

You could restrict this to only work on a certain type by giving `addd` an explicit type signature, so that it isn't at all polymorphic in the arguments, e.g.:

```
addd :: Monad m => Int -> Int -> m Int
-- or,
addd :: Monad m => Integer -> Integer -> m Integer
```

Or, you could inform GHC of the input type when you call `addd`, e.g.:

```
d <- addd 4 (8 :: Integer)
```

and then the type inference will infer that `4` and `d` are both `Integer`s.

Lastly, you can give `d` a type. Either when you use it (if you use `d` multiple times, you only need a single annotation), like so:

```
printf "%d" (d :: Integer)
```

Or when you set it (requires the GHC extension `ScopedTypeVariables`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

[...]
add = do
    (d :: Integer) <- addd 4 8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped! But I have to admit that this looks really ugly. Isn't there a prettier way around it? Also another understanding question:
Why isn't it sufficient to have the Num type for the return value of addd? Why do I have to tell haskell about Integer?

Comment: Ah I see it is due to the formating %d which demands d to be of Integer type.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain what is wrong with your program.

- Try giving explicit type signature, it helps compiler to infer types and also you to understand your program better.
- addd is a pure function so don't use return.
- return in not what you expect coming from an imperative background.
- why do you need `printf` after all, use `print` or `putStrLn` if you want to output to console. Use `show` if you want to convert a type (whose `show` instance is defined) to string.

Here  is your corrected program anyways

```
import Text.Printf

program :: String
program = do
    let d = addd 4 8
    printf "%d" d

addd :: Int -> Int -> Int
addd x y = x+y
```

You can write it just using `print` as

```
program :: IO ()
program = do
    print $ addd 4 8

addd :: Int -> Int -> Int
addd x y = x+y
```

Try reading some introductory material on [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials)

Comment: The background was to use printf for nice tabular formatted output on the screen. I know the basic print statement, but it lags some formating.